# AJAX request terminated abnormally with select photo uploads in Drupal

Tags: ajax, image, drupal, upload, drupal-7

I'm busy fixing an issue on a site a friend runs for her work. I have worked on this site before, and this is the only Drupal site I have ever worked on, so I am somewhat of a newbie to Drupal. The original dev decided they no longer wanted to maintain it quite some time ago and kind of disappeared shortly after.

The issue:- Most photos upload fine however some cause the following error:

> An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally. Debugging information follows. 
>   Path: /?q=file/ajax/field_accom_image/und/form--5hp1P7pzFdShaND24CsiI7QNe3f9bApEq9Gu78bRZg 
>   StatusText: n/a 
>   ResponseText: Bad Request Your browser sent a request that this server could not understand. Apache Server at REAL_URL_REDACTED Port 80 
>   ReadyState: undefined

I have found "An AJAX HTTP request terminated abnormally" errors on StackOverflow and the Drupal site, however, none of them had a "ResponseText" of "Bad Request" and a "ReadyState" of "undefined" simultaneously.

This didn't stop me from trying troubleshooting from those answers, such as setting the $base_url variable in settings.php, checking and changing permissions on the server, disable the overlay feature for the admin settings, compressing the image to a smaller file size, dropping the image resolution, removing all possible metadata from the image, checking the upload max file size in the php config.

Drupal version is 7.59

Comment: Start with some trivial reasons - maybe some images are too large? Try bigger and smaller file sizes. Check what's the upload size limit.

Comment: The image that is causing the error was originally bigger than the others but I  compressed it to the same size as the others and smaller than the others. Both still cause the error. I even changed the resolution to the same as the others. However, even with the original size it is still well within the upload limits. I do believe the issue is caused by the image but I can't work out what it must be or how to solve it.

Comment: Go for Apache log. See what's the issue recorded there.

Comment: My friend has decided to just avoid all the photos that are causing issues. I think shes going to try get the image files again from the photographer and see if that helps.